# Embedding content - Use iFrame, JS/jQuery, or what?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

**This gets somewhat complex, so first, a little background:**

We're redesigning a video platform that we use across internal applications and our customers use as well for video delivery. The goal is for our customers to be able to embed stuff easily to put it on their own sites, as you would expect. Thus far, we've given a one-line script tag to do this, like so, which drops a player on a page:

```
<script src="http://vod.nimbushd.com/player/player.ashx?mediaItemAssetId=8413adeb-6b15-4606-a771-637527539093&h=480&w=720" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[Sample Page with the script above](http://static.nimbushd.com/Brandon/EmbedV1Sample.htm)

This is just an ASP.NET handler that returns some Javascript, which, in turn renders some HTML for the player.

That works well enough for a player, but now on to the redesign.

We're now targeting different players for different browser types, HTML5 fallback in the absence of Silverlight, and some other bells/whistles. One of our big feature requests is to be able to serve up a player with add'l video gallery, Disqus comments, Twitter/Facebook share/like buttons; basically, regardless of the philosophy that these are things that should live natively on the customer site, **we need to be able to design more complex features and serve them up the easiest embed-style possible**.

I guess one school of thought is that we almost need an iFrame that behaves like embedded content (no scrollbars, sizing, and so on).

We're tossing around ideas like more complex Javascript-rendering HTML that could get impossible to maintain pretty quickly, whether advanced features should just be Rich content (Silverlight/Flash), or if there's some in-between like a jQuery partial page refresh or something.

Hoping to learn from some folks who have already gone down this road - **as an end-user, how would you expect to embed content**, and **as a content provider, how do you serve that content in embeddable form?**

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would prefer a one line script to include for this

```
<script src="..." type="text/javascript"
   data-container="someId"
   data-otherParam="..."
   data-beforeLoad="someFunction"
   ...
></script>
```

Passing all the configuration options in as html5 data attributes would be the most convenient. It would also be great if we can pass in a function name that you would call to give the end-user even more control where necessary.

As for what your actual code does. I would recommend you have the script do all your logic and have it make JSONP calls to a webservice to get any data it needs. As for the HTML rendering I recommend you use any templating engine and reference a templating file directly loading them from your server either directly or over JSONP if neccesary.

As for embedding your actual data/html pick a `<div>` or create a new one and render partial templates to the children of that `<div>`.

Alternatively you go down the easy route and just ask the user to embed an `<iframe>`. This solution isn't as nice.

Comment: In what circumstances does this method fail?

Comment: @routeNpingme some of the technique I've mentioned aren't really stable in IE6. You might have problems with excessive firewall securities. This takes arguably longer to develop and is only more manageable/maintainable if you've worked templating engines in javascript and have worked with setting up JSONP data services before.